# What is a reliable, authoritative source to find out what the latest stable release of Ubuntu is?

Tags: release-management

What is  a reliable, authoritative source to find out what the latest stable release of Ubuntu is (if there is one)? Ideally this should exist somewhere fixed on the web, and should *always* tell you what the current latest stable version of Ubuntu is.

At the moment http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop mentions 14.04 and doesn't mention 14.10, so one might think it's 14.04. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/ calls 14.04.1 the "latest version" (the distinction between 14.04 and 14.04.1 is not my point here). But http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/ doesn't mention "beta" or "RC" anywhere, which leads one to think it's the final release. But it's not clear if one is "supposed" to look at that page directly. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UtopicUnicorn/ReleaseNotes sounds like it's 14.10, but then it's a wiki page...

(Note: the question is really what is stated in the first sentence, not "what's the latest stable release right now?")

Answer (score 1):

The site https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases pretty clearly indicates that 14.10 is a future release, which should indicate to you that this is not yet a stable version.  14.04 is listed as a current release, supported until April 2019 which should indicate to you that Canonical considers this to be a stable release.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

That's my answer to this somewhat silly question. If there's a stable release it will be put on the downloads page when it's ready.